# Loop through array containing itemIds, fetch data from api per itemid

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have an array like below containing itemId's. I want to loop through the array and for every itemId fetch the corresponding data from a API and thereafter collect the results and render DOM. Can't get it working....

```
gtinArray = [
    "07314224054620",
    "07314225267340",
    "07313929649155",
    "07314226417799",
    "07314226224342"
]

  getItem(gtin) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const URL = "http://localhost:7071/api/GetItem?Gtin=" + gtin
      fetch(URL)
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(item => {
          resolve(item)
        })
    })
  }
  

  pupulateCart() {
    let itemRequests = []

    gtinArray.forEach(gtin => {
      itemRequests.push(getItem(gtin))
    })

    Promise.all(itemRequests)
    .then(allItemData => {
      console.log("All item data")
      console.log(allItemData)
    })

  }
```

Comment: `Can't get it working` this is not helpful.  It just means that out of infinite possible outcomes, the one that you expected didn't occur.  Tell us what DID happen, including any errors or network failures.

Comment: Are you seeing the items logged by `console.log(allItemData)`? What else do you need to do>?

Comment: It never reach the point console.log(allItemData)

Comment: In the future you should add in the exact errors you are getting, if any. Hopefully the answer below helps.

Comment: ... and to all the answers `gtinArray` of cause will be passed as parameter to `pupulateCart`.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const gtinArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

function getItem(gtin) {
  const URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + gtin
  return fetch(URL).then(response => response.json());
}


async function populateCart() {
  let itemRequests = []
  itemRequests = gtinArray.map(gtin => getItem(gtin));
  return await Promise.all(itemRequests)
}

(async function () {
  const data = await populateCart();
  console.log(data);
})();
```

Comment: A valid answer, noticable differeance is the use of `map` instead of defining the function as `const getItem = (gtin) => {...`. The `map` function essentially turns it into the `(gtin) => {...` definition.

Comment: `await` is not necessary on `Promise.all`, or the `await` on `populateCart` is redundant.

Comment: @DaveMeehan both `awaits` are necessary if you use `await` on `Promise.all`. If I don't put `await` on `populateCart`, `data` variable will hold a pending promise. Only the await on `Promise.all` is optional and that varies from developer to developer. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/degbckpu/) is what you're referring to I guess. Both approaches are valid and it's just a matter of choice.

Comment: @Salvino Only because you defined `populateCart` as `async` (your fiddle is what I mean), but the async/await is essentially redundant.  You gain nothing by awaiting the Promise.all only to have the async function wrap it in a promise.

Comment: @DaveMeehan I think you're confused. Both methods are valid. As I said, I can either wait for `Promise.all` or not, which will return a pending promise which I can await for in the subsequent function call. Again, these are just preferences that vary from dev to dev. Since I've used await for `Promise.all` I have to declare the function that holds it as async. If you want, you can skip that. totally depends on you.

Comment: @Salvino I'm not confused, I'm pointing out that you're (in effect) returning a Promise for a Promise, and unnecessarily so.  Your async/await use on the `populateCart` implementation is redundant and obfuscates what's going on.  I think that's worth clarifying for the sake of the OP's understanding.  No need for IIFE to cajole js into running your code.

Answer (score 0):

This may be your problem, your `getItem` function is not in the proper format.
Also any async calls need to be contained within an async function.

```js
gtinArray = [
  "07314224054620",
  "07314225267340",
  "07313929649155",
  "07314226417799",
  "07314226224342"
]

const getItem = (gtin) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const URL = "http://localhost:7071/api/GetItem?Gtin=" + gtin
    fetch(URL)
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(item => {
        resolve(item)
      })
  })
}


async function pupulateCart() {
  let itemRequests = []

  gtinArray.forEach(gtin => {
    itemRequests.push(getItem(gtin))
  })

  Promise.all(itemRequests)
    .then(allItemData => {
      console.log("All item data")
      console.log(allItemData)
    })

}

pupulateCart();
```

Comment: Answer updated, but it won't run correctly unless you actually have a localhost server running on port 7071.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with promises, no need for async/await (although easily convertible should you prefer that style).

```js
const gtinArray = [
    "07314224054620",
    "07314225267340",
    "07313929649155",
    "07314226417799",
    "07314226224342"
]

function getItem(gtin) {
    const URL = "http://localhost:7071/api/GetItem?Gtin=" + gtin

    // next line is to remove the external server and just give us the URL back
    // (just for the sake of StackOverflow example)
    return Promise.resolve(URL)

    // next line is what you'd actually want to make the fetch and convert json
    // return fetch(URL).then(result => result.json())
}


function populateCart() {
    // return promise, or caller can't chain 
    // (even if allItemData is processed in .then())
    return Promise.all(gtinArray.map(gtin => getItem(gtin)))
        .then(allItemData => {
            console.log("All item data")
            console.log(allItemData)
        })
}

populateCart().then(() => console.log('done'));
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, huge thanks for you assistance, greatly appreciated!

I have now updated my code according to below. I still don't get it working unfortunately. When i click the button triggering the populateCart() function console.log("Running populateCart") is the only thing thats gets logged to console. I can se server side that al five requests get handled but the session never seem to close. If I kill the server I get a console error for each fetch. Please see attached screens.

[image]

```
import { LitElement, html, css} from 'lit'
import './button-done'
import './cart-item'
import { Client } from './client'
import { Queue } from './queue'

const { ipcRenderer } = window.require('electron')

export class GateApp extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      title: { type: String },
      customer: { type: String },
      email: { type: String },
      items: {type: Object},
      gtinArray: {type: Object},
    }
  }

  static get styles() {
    return css`
      :host {
        min-height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
        color: #1a2b42;
        max-width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: var(--gate-app-background-color);
      }

      .frame2 {
        background-color: #CAEEC2;
      }

      #pageLayout {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      #frameTop {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
      }

      #frameLeft {
        width: 50px;
        height: calc(100vh - 100px);
      }

      #frameRight {
        width: 50px;
        height: calc(100vh - 100px);
      }

      #frameBottom {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
      }

      #centerRow {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
      }

      #content {
        width: calc(100vw - 100px);
        height: calc(100vh - 100px);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      #cartItemContainer {
        width: calc(100vw - 100px);
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        align-content: flex-start;
      }

      .cart-item {
        margin: 15px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 4px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
    `
  }

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.title = 'Shoppingbag'
    this.customer = ''
    this.email = ''
    
    this.items = []
    //this.gtinArray = []
    this.gtinArray = ['07314224178272', '07314227150152', '07314227475811', '07314228873272', '07314227368533']

    this.client = new Client()
    this.gtinQueue = new Queue()
    this.timer
  }

  firstUpdated() {
    ipcRenderer.on("new-scan", (_, tag) => {
      //console.log("Received message from Electron: ", tag)
      
      if (this.isBag(tag)) {
      
      } else {
        this.handleScan(tag)
      }

    })

  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <div id="pageLayout">
        <div id="frameTop" class="frame"></div>
        <div id="centerRow">
          <div id="frameLeft" class="frame"></div>
          <div id="content">

            <h1>${this.title}</h1>
            <div id="cartItemContainer">
              
              ${this.items.map(item => html`
              
              <cart-item
                class="cart-item"
                imageUrl="${item.assetUrl}"
                itemName="${item.productName}"
                itemPrice="${item.whitePrice}"
                artNr="${item.articleId}"
                size="Medium"
              ></cart-item>
              
              `)}

            </div>
            <br>
            <button-done @click="${this.populateCart}"></button-done>

          </div>
          <div id="frameRight" class="frame"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="frameBottom" class="frame"></div>
        </div>
    `
  }

  itemInCart(gtin) {
    let itemInCart = false
    this.items.forEach(item => {
      if (item.gtin === gtin) {
        itemInCart = true
      }
    })
    return itemInCart
  }

  isBag(tag) {
    if (tag.substring(0, 2) === '00')
      return true
    else
      return false
  }

  handleScan(tag) {
    var found = false
    this.gtinArray.forEach(gtin => {
      if (gtin == tag) {
        found = true
      }
    })

    if(!found) {
      this.gtinArray.push(tag)
      this.gtinQueue.enqueue(tag)
        clearTimeout(this.timer)
        this.runTimer()
      console.log(this.gtinArray)
    }
  }

  getItem = (gtin) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const URL = "http://localhost:7071/api/GetItem?Gtin=" + gtin
      fetch(URL)
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(item => {
          resolve(item)
        })
        
    })
  }
  
  async populateCart() {
    console.log("Running populateCart")
    let itemRequests = []
  
    this.gtinArray.forEach(gtin => {
      itemRequests.push(this.getItem(gtin))
    })
  
    Promise.all(itemRequests)
      .then(allItemData => {
        console.log("All item data")
        console.log(allItemData)
      })
  
  }

}

customElements.define('gate-app', GateApp)
```

Comment: If this.gtinArray only contain one entry as the following, everything works just fine. this.gtinArray = ['07314224178272]